# missing mysql.sock after new install

Tags: mysql, macos

I recently upgraded to a new macbook pro and haven't been able to get mysql to install.  I have been trying to install using the:

mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg

which 'should' work for my machine, but is not.  After installing the three pieces (mysql.pkg, 
startup.pkg, prefpane) I get nothing.  Trying to start mySQL through the prefpane freezes sysprefs.  Trying to start via the terminal gets this error:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

So I deleted all of the mysql install files and reinstalled following these instructions:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/12820394

when I get to the step where I would set up the root password i get the following error:

error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!

This is perhaps due to the fact that there are no mysql related files in /tmp ?  I can't find anything *.sock anywhere on my machine at all.  I really don't know much about server admin, so I could be totally confused and off here.

Answer (score 1):

It can have moved to /var/mysql/mysql.sock. I think it is the new position. You may need to point your php.ini to that or create a symbolic link to ln -s /var/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock...

Comment: my /var/ does not have a mysql subfolder.  Where else could it be?